# Polymer not loading ts web component with polymer serve

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymer, web-component, lit-element

Following the LitElement guide here: https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/start

I'm literally following it by the books and then running
`polymer serve` in the root directory of the project.

I even copy/pasted over every file from their example stackblitz pages. Am I not supposed to use polymer serve or something?

All I get is blank page, and it seems to not recognize the customElement

[image: Nothing created under my-element]

my-element.ts:

```
import { LitElement, html, customElement, property } from 'lit-element';

@customElement('my-element')
export class MyElement extends LitElement {
  @property()
  foo = 'foo';

  render() {
    return html`
      <p>hi!</p>
    `;
  }
}
```

index.ts:

```
import './my-element.ts';
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script src="/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js"></script>

    <title>lit-element code sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-element></my-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.10",
    "lit-element": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I even copy/pasted over every file from their example stackblitz pages

Actually Stackblitz TS projects follow a particular structure in which `index.ts` is treated as the entry point of the TypeScript code, automatically compiled and imported in the final result.

The local scenario is pretty different: you have to choose a build tool to compile TS files and import the result in `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- This may differ depending on your build configuration -->
    <script src="./path/to/my-element.js" type="module"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-element></my-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can use [`tsc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) directly or a module bundler such as [Webpack + ts-loader](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) or [Rollup + rollup-plugin-typescript2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-typescript2). This really depends on the complexity and requirements of your projects and what browsers you want to support.

Comment: Ah ok, that was my biggest confusion as to how they did it without that script tag.

Comment: Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8081/index.ts' because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable. So I'm guessing it doesn't like the fact that I'm giving it a typescript file. I'm doing src="./my-element.ts". Do I need to set up a whole build/package config thing to get it to work with ts?

Comment: Yes, browsers don't understand `.ts` files: you have to compile them to js. I updated the answer with a little bit of context on compilers/bundlers. Tell me if you need more info